# How to use Spring Cloud Sleuth for tracing Kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, spring-cloud-sleuth

How to trace Kafka based events using Spring Cloud sleuth? Whatever examples I saw were for rest APIs. I am looking for kafka-clients library.

Also is it a good idea to use Spring cloud sleuth for this or should I pass my traceIds via headers manually?

Comment: https://github.com/openzipkin-contrib/brave-kafka-interceptor#brave-kafka-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

From the Spring Cloud Sleuth documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/docs/current/reference/html/integrations.html#sleuth-messaging-spring-kafka-streams-integration) it says that the integration is provided with Kafka Streams ( Sleuth internally uses library [Brave](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave) for instrumentation). The property through which this can be enabled/disabled is `spring.sleuth.messaging.kafka.streams.enabled` ( true/false)

> We instrument the KafkaStreams KafkaClientSupplier so that tracing
> headers get injected into the Producer and Consumer's. A
> KafkaStreamsTracing bean allows for further instrumentation through
> additional TransformerSupplier and ProcessorSupplier methods.

For an example configuration/code you can take a look [here](https://github.com/richardkabiling/kafka-sleuth-maven-java).